# NSURLConnection returning 0 bytes data

Tags: iphone, objective-c, request, nsurlconnection, synchronous

I am sending nsurlconection request with synchronous method as below.
its working fine with simulator but not working on devices.

here is my code

```
/////// FOR POST
    NSString *postData=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"message=%@",
                         [[dicGlobal valueForKey:@"giftMessage"] stringByURLEncode]];

    NSData *myRequestData = [ NSData dataWithBytes: [ postData UTF8String ] length: [ postData length]];

    NSLog(@"%@",myRequestData);

    NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:strUrl];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request=[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];
    [ request setHTTPMethod: @"POST" ];
    [ request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"content-type"];
    [ request setHTTPBody: myRequestData ];
    NSURLResponse *response;
    NSError *error;
    NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest: request returningResponse:&response error:&error];
    if (returnData) {
        NSString *content = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:[returnData bytes]];
        NSLog(@"%@",content);
        TBXML *tbxml=[TBXML tbxmlWithXMLString:content];
```

Please check my code and help me out where is the issue.

Thanks & Regards 
Shivam

Comment: what does it do on the device exactly? What is returnData on the device?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Implement this code

```
 NSString *postData=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"message=%@",
                             [[dicGlobal valueForKey:@"giftMessage"] stringByURLEncode]];

        NSData *myRequestData = [ NSData dataWithBytes: [ postData UTF8String ] length: [ postData length]];

        NSLog(@"%@",myRequestData);

        NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:strUrl];
      NSMutableURLRequest *postRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url
                                                                   cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
                                                               timeoutInterval:30.0];
        [ request setHTTPMethod: @"POST" ];
        [ request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"content-type"];
        [ request setHTTPBody: myRequestData ];
        NSURLResponse *response;
        NSError *error;
        NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest: request returningResponse:&response error:&error];
        if (returnData) {
            NSString *content = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:[returnData bytes]];
            NSLog(@"%@",content);
            TBXML *tbxml=[TBXML tbxmlWithXMLString:content];
```

Answer (score 0):

In this line:

```
NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:strUrl];
```

what is strUrl. Where is it declared and assigned?

I'm not sure but looks like your URL is accessible from your Mac (maybe it's a resource on your LAN) but not from your device. (Your device connects through some other Wi-Fi network or 3G?).

Try creating a Wi-Fi network from your Mac and connect your device to this network.
Hope this should solve the problem.

Comment: Yes you are right it may be issue but. There are lot of webservices running from same server and these are returning data with get method

Comment: Or put the url into safari on the phone and see what results you get.